# What does 'Immediacy' mean in following context?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, sentence

> The composition of "In the Garden" is notable for its sense of
> immediacy and intimacy.
> [image]

Comment: Straight from dictionary: "the quality of bringing one into direct and instant involvement with something"  - does that definition help?

Comment: That's exactly what I can't understand @JamesK

Comment: Please add your dictionar research to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight from dictionary: "the quality of bringing one into direct and instant involvement with something".

The painting has a quality that means you are directly and instantly involved in the scene.  Unlike some paintings that are like windows and you feel separated from the scene, or some paintings need to be carefully studied and analysed.  With this painting, you immediately feel connected to it.

That is the claim.  Writing it down doesn't make it true.

Comment: Now I got it. Thank you sir.